# Carbohydrate diet and dental health

Tags: evolution, nutrition, human-evolution, carbohydrates, teeth

I read that human started carbohydrates rich diet after adopting agriculture before that meat was main energy source which has comparatively less carbohydrate. High carbohydrate started destroying human teeth. 
Would a keto diet (high protein fat) diet and low carb diet reduce cavity in teeth?

Comment: Where's your reference for the claim?

Comment: @GrahamChiu http://www.businessinsider.com/growing-crops-human-cavities-increase-2016-3     there are plenty other sources on google

Comment: Please run an English spelling check (and preferably a grammar check too) before posting. They come free on web browsers. You should at least check that the five words of your title are spelled correctly. And pay heed to @GrahamChiu. You need to cite your sources for assertions in your question. It is not enough to say there are plenty on Google (by which I assume you mean the web). If you cite them we can judge their quality. Are they papers in a peer-reviewed journal or just quack health site?